# Wordpress add javascript in footer

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I need to add a script in the site footer.
I'm just referencing the footer.php:

`<script src="wp-content/file/script.js"></ script>`

At Home functions normally, but when access a page child he does not find because search the directory:

`site/page-child/wp-content/file/script.js`.

I saw that I have to use:

`wp_enqueue_script ()`

But where should I put this code?

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a "/" before your url in order to start it from root like :

```
<script src="/wp-content/file/script.js"></ script>
```

Indeed at home page it looks for yoursite.com/wp-content but on other pages it searches yoursite.com/current-page/wp-content and obviously it results in 404.

Adding / make it always look for yoursite.com/wp-content

Comment: In this way it accesses localhost and not localhost/project

Comment: @Daniel Indeed but I wanted to make him understand why it wasn't working, then it's just adaptation. Considering that he uses wordpress, an even better answer would be to use wordpress custom url

Answer (score 1):

Adding `<script src="wp-content/file/script.js"></ script>` is not a clean way to load your JS files because this is not a relative URL and when you active your child theme probably your theme will not load your JS file, the solution is :

```
<script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/script.js"></script>
```

You need to add this to your `footer.php` file in your theme directory `wp-content\themes\your_theme\footer.php`

but the best way is to use WP hooks to include your scripts, first you need to register them using

```
wp_register_script( 'my_script_name', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/script.js' );
```

then simply load them

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script_name' );
```

Don't try to register and enqueue your scripts directly in your footer.php file, instead create a method in your `functions.php` template file then load your scripts using

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

Note: To enqueue your scripts to the footer you need to set `$in_footer` parameter to true.

Checkout [wp_enqueue_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for more information.

Comment: In which file I register

`wp_register_script`?

How do I upload my js my pc file to the wordpress?

Comment: Copy your JS file in your theme project here : `wp-content\themes\your_theme\js`
Then go to `wp-content\themes\your_theme\footer.php` and add this :
`<script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/script.js"></script>`
To use `wp_register_script`, add it to `wp-content\themes\your_theme\functions.php` if the file doesn't exist create it and it will be automatically loaded..

Comment: Here an example of how you can use this :
`function load_my_script(){
wp_register_script( 'my_script_name', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/script.js' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script_name' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );`

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to use WordPress, you can replace

```
    <script src="wp-content/file/script.js"></ script>
```

with:

```
    <script src="<?php site_url('/wp-content/file/script.js'); ?>"></script>
```

Comment: Could you please check the source code that is produced after performing this change and report back what the output for this `<script>` block was?